# why i am getting the error "Cannot call constructor " when adding constructer in my cotroller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am newcomer in codeigniter 4. whenever i am adding constructer function in one of my controller  i am getting the error "Error Cannot call constructor.

```
namespace App\Controllers;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 
    public function index()
    {
        helper('cookie','form','url');
        $image = \Config\Services::image(); //this is the image library or class  loadig
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is it complaining about, the constructor of `Home` or the parent?

Comment: `BaseController` does not define a constructor of its own. Therefore there's no explicit parent constructor to call, and you get such an error.